# 2d pchip in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization, interpolation

I know values of z on a (x,y) meshgrid, defined by xgrid, ygrid.

xgrid, and ygrid are not uniform grids.

I need to interpolate value of z off the grid points.

I need interpolants similar to 'pchip', because the problem at hand requires shape-preseving, and 'pchip' has better shape-preserving properties than e.g. 'spline'.

My current code:

```
xgrid = [0.01 0.1 0.5 1]';
ygrid = [0.01 0.1 0.5 1];
z = 0.01./(repmat(xgrid,[1 4]).*repmat(ygrid,[4 1]));
x1 = 0.05;
y1 = 0.05;

[xmesh,ymesh] = ndgrid(xgrid,ygrid);
interpolant1  = griddedInterpolant(xmesh,ymesh,z,'cubic');
z1            = interpolant1(x1, y1);

for ix = 1:length(xgrid);
    interpolant2(ix) = interp1(ygrid, z(ix,:), y1, 'pchip');
end
z1            = interp1(xgrid, interpolant2,   x1, 'pchip');
```

In my example, interpolant1 will use 'spline' instead of 'cubic' and seems less accurate due to overshooting (http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2012/07/16/splines-and-pchips/). However, interpolant1 is much faster.

My main question: what can I do to make my code for interpolant2 more efficient? vectorization? use an alternative to interp1?

Comment: Are you familiar with [`griddata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html)?

Comment: no, but I can learn if it helps.

Comment: Well, `griddata` has a cubic interpolation method that is local. I'm not sure about efficiency, nor overshoots. But it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Andras: `griddata` is 3x faster than doing `interp1` twice. However, it is still 6x slower than `griddedInterpolant` on an uniform grid. There has to be a way to take advantage of the regular grid structure. I guess I should read the code underlying `interp1' and `griddedInterpolant'.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I thought your input was scattered. Have you tried [`interp2d`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html)? From the manual it seems like it uses a local interpolant, so it should also be less susceptible to overshoots than spline (but this is only a hunch).

Comment: Thanks Andras, I tried `interp2`, which is equivalent to `griddedInterpolant` in the Matlab version I am using. I cannot find `interp2d'. I found this though---a post from way back looking for 2d pchip to no avail: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/75138